# I cannot redirect in tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter

My aim is to open on the same window when the button is pressed. But when I run the program, it opens in 2 windows at the same time.

I want it to open when the button is pressed.

How can I do it?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
 
master = tk.Tk()
uruns = tk.Tk()

master.geometry("300x300")
uruns.geometry("300x300")
 
def buttonCallback():
    mas = master.Label(uruns, text="Urunler listesi")
    mas.pack()
 
urunler = tk.Button(master, text="Click", command=buttonCallback)
 
label_1 = tk.Label(master, text="Bolat Aktar ürün yönetim sistemi")
 
# Use the grid geometry manager to put the widgets in the respective position
label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
urunler.grid(row=1, column=0)

 
# The application mainloop
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I dont understand. You want to open the same window from the button?

Comment: @Cool Cloud I want `def buttonCallBack` to run on the same window without opening a separate window when the button is pressed. But when I open the program from the beginning, it is active in two windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is pretty easy.
you cant do twice `Tk()` in your code and any tkinter code should be have one `Tk()`.
so if you want to make another window you will need `Toplevel()` it's the same as `Tk()`.
so there are 2 methods to do this:

**Method 1 make a `Toplevel()` in the function:**

so you want to open a new window with that button right ?
and you dont want to run twice windows in the beginning.

1. delete your `uruns = tk.Tk()`
2. in your function `buttonCallBack` do this:

```py
def buttonCallBack:
    uruns = tk.Toplevel()
    uruns .geometry("300x300")
    mas   = tk.Label(uruns, text="Urunler listesi")
    mas   .pack()
```

the full code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
 
master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry("300x300")
 
def buttonCallback():
    uruns  = tk.Toplevel()
    uruns  .geometry("300x300")
    mas    = Label(uruns, text="Urunler listesi")
    mas    .pack()
 
urunler = tk.Button(master, text="Click", command=buttonCallback)
 
label_1 = tk.Label(master, text="Bolat Aktar ürün yönetim sistemi")
 
# Use the grid geometry manager to put the widgets in the respective position
label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
urunler.grid(row=1, column=0)

 
# The application mainloop
master.mainloop()
```

**Method 2(the best) show/hide your another window `Toplevel()`:**

to show your `Toplevel()` use `Toplvel.deiconify()`

to hide your `Toplevel()` use `Toplvel.withdraw ()`

so do this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

master = tk.Tk()
uruns  = tk.Toplevel()

uruns  .withdraw() # Hide the second window

uruns  .geometry("300x300")
master .geometry("300x300")

def buttonCallback():

    uruns .deiconify() # Show the second window

    mas   = tk.Label(uruns, text="Urunler listesi")
    mas   .pack()

urunler = tk.Button(master, text="Click", command=buttonCallback)

label_1 = tk.Label(master, text="Bolat Aktar ürün yönetim sistemi")

# Use the grid geometry manager to put the widgets in the respective position
label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
urunler.grid(row=1, column=0)

# The application mainloop
master.mainloop()
```